# plus member of array dependent on the another array members

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have a table in my database like bottom

**course**     **statuse**  
ICDL         1

ICDL          1

ICDL         0

3DMAX      1

autocat      1

autocad     0

and i want to show the date table like this.

**course**     **call**     **register**  
ICDL          2         1

3DMAX       1         0

autocat       1         1

i want to delete repetitive course.
also i want plus the status int her course name

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the direct approach:

```
<?php
$input = [
  [
    'course' => 'ICDL',
    'statuse' => 1,
  ],
  [
    'course' => 'ICDL',
    'statuse' => 1,
  ],
  [
    'course' => 'ICDL',
    'statuse' => 0,
  ],
  [
    'course' => '3DMAX',
    'statuse' => 1,
  ],
  [
    'course' => 'autocat',
    'statuse' => 1,
  ],
  [
    'course' => 'autocat',
    'statuse' => 0,
  ]
]
;

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
  $course = &$entry['course'];

  if (!array_key_exists($course, $output)) {
    $output[$course] = [
      'call' => 0,
      'register' => 0
    ];
  }

  switch($entry['statuse']) {
    case 1: 
      $action = 'call';
      break;
    case 0: 
      $action = 'register';
      break;
    default: 
      throw new Exception("undefined action '$action'!");
  }
  $output[$course][$action]++;
});

print_r($output);
```

The obvious output is:

```
Array
(
    [ICDL] => Array
        (
            [call] => 2
            [register] => 1
        )

    [3DMAX] => Array
        (
            [call] => 1
            [register] => 0
        )

    [autocat] => Array
        (
            [call] => 1
            [register] => 1
        )
)
```